# How do I allow my program to accept different inputs from the user in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a program that allows the user to enter integers into a vector. Once the user is done with the first vector the program prints the contents of the vector and how big it is, the problem arises after the first vector when the user is suppose to be able to input integers into a second vector. My program just skips over that and doesn't let the user input anything. Code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print1(vector <int> const& vector1) {
    std::cout << "\nThe elements of Vector 1 are: ";

    for (int v1{ 0 }; v1 < vector1.size(); ++v1) {
        cout << vector1.at(v1) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\nThe size of Vector 1 is: " << vector1.size();
}

void print2(vector <int> const& vector2) {
    std::cout << "\nThe elements of Vector 2 are: ";

    for (int v2{ 0 }; v2 < vector2.size(); ++v2) {
        cout << vector2.at(v2) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\nThe size of Vector 2 is: " << vector2.size();
}

int main() {
    vector <int> vector1(0);
    vector <int> vector2(0);

    int data1{ 0 };
    std::cout << "Enter data for Vector 1: ";
    while (cin >> data1) {
        vector1.push_back(data1);
    }
    print1(vector1);


    int data2{ 0 };
    std::cout << "\n\nEnter data for Vector 2: ";
    while (cin >> data2) {
        vector2.push_back(data2);
    }
    print2(vector2);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT********
Thanks to Nathan in the comments all I ended up having to do was add cin.clear(); right above the code for the second vector.

Comment: It looks like you keep reading until `cin`'s fail bit is set. At that point, subsequent reads won't go off; the condition for the second `while` loop will be immediately `false`. You need to `clear` it between reading in `vector1` and `vector2`.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thank you so so much, Im very new to programming and after spending a good 30 mins on this the fact that all it was was adding cin.clear(); inbetween it was astonishing.

Comment: Either of you please create an answer, to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. @NathanPierson

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation the first loop is not exiting.

Here is a working and little improved implementation for the same. In this we are terminating the loop with any non-number input like a terminating '.':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print_vector(vector <int> const& vector1) {

    for (int v1{ 0 }; v1 < vector1.size(); ++v1) {
        cout << vector1.at(v1) << ' ';
    }
}

void read_vector(vector <int>& vector1) {
    int data1{ 0 };
    while (cin >> data1) {
        vector1.push_back(data1);
    }

    cin.clear();
    string term;
    cin >> term;
}

int main() {
    vector <int> vector1(0);
    vector <int> vector2(0);

    std::cout << "Enter data for Vector 1: ";
    read_vector(vector1);
    std::cout << "\nThe elements of Vector 1 are: ";
    print_vector(vector1);
    std::cout << "\nThe size of Vector 1 is: " << vector1.size() << endl;

    std::cout << "Enter data for Vector 2: ";
    read_vector(vector2);
    std::cout << "\nThe elements of Vector 2 are: ";
    print_vector(vector2);
    std::cout << "\nThe size of Vector 2 is: " << vector1.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter data for Vector 1: 1 2 3.

The elements of Vector 1 are: 1 2 3
The size of Vector 1 is: 3
Enter data for Vector 2: 4 5 6.

The elements of Vector 2 are: 4 5 6
The size of Vector 2 is: 3
```